Prove/disprove $\sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor {x_i}^{y} \right\rfloor \leq \left\lfloor x^y\right\rfloor$ for $x_i,y\geq 1.$
If $x_i,y\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 1},\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = x,$ then it is obviously true that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^y \leq x^y,$ due to the Binomial theorem.
After trying various inputs for $x_i$ and $y$, I suspect that the following inequality is also true for any $x_i,y\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}$:
$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor {x_i}^{y} \right\rfloor \leq \left\lfloor x^y\right\rfloor. $$
But I can't seem to prove it immediately.
Since $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor {x_i}^{y} \right\rfloor \leq \sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^y,\ $ it would be nice if $\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^y \leq \left\lfloor x^y\right\rfloor,\ $ for then we would be done. But the latter inequality is false: take $n=2,\ x_1=1.7,\ x_2=1.7,\ y=1.31.$

I think I am on the right path now looking at cases like $\left\lfloor {5.9}^{1.01} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor {5.9}^{1.01} \right\rfloor$ vs $\left\lfloor {11.8}^{1.01} \right\rfloor$ which gives $\left\lfloor 6.00565 \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor 6.00565 \right\rfloor$ vs $\left\lfloor 12.09 \right\rfloor.$
Another case is: $\left\lfloor {5.9}^{1.01} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor {31.9}^{1.01} \right\rfloor$ vs $\left\lfloor {37.8}^{1.01} \right\rfloor$ which gives $\left\lfloor 6.00565 \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor 33.024 \right\rfloor$ vs $\left\lfloor 39.198 \right\rfloor.$

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor {x_i}^{y} \right\rfloor \leq \sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^y
\le x^y
$$
and since the expression on the left-hand side is an integer it follows that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor {x_i}^{y} \right\rfloor \leq \max \{ k \in \Bbb Z \mid k \le x^y \} = \left\lfloor x^y\right\rfloor.
$$
Remark: The restriction $x_i \ge 1$ is not needed. If $x_1, \ldots, x_n > 0$, $y \ge 1$ and $x = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ then $x_i/x \le 1$, so that
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{x_i}{x}\right)^y \le \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{x} = 1 \, .
$$
This also follows from the fact that $f(t) = t^y$ is convex on $[0, \infty)$ with $f(0) = 0$, and therefore superadditive.

Of course. I missed that...
